# How do I localize a Button's ToolTip text in UWP - WinUI 2

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, winui

I'm making a UWP app with WinUI 2.8.
I have a button control, and with a basic ToolTip in it.

**How can I localize the ToolTip using localization tables?**

Here's my XAML code of the button:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="SaveB" 
    x:Uid="Save" 
    Content="Save" 
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Saves the input." 
    Click="SaveB_Click" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create resources files targeting different languages in your app and save the localized string in the files.

Here are the steps to create a localized string for en-US. You could take it as example.

1. On the Application tab, confirm that the Default language is set appropriately (for example, "en" or "en-US").
2. Under your project node, create a new folder and name it "Strings".
3. Under `Strings`, create a new sub-folder and name it "en-US".
4. Under `en-US`, create a new Resources File (.resw) and confirm that it is named "Resources.resw".
5. Save the resource strings into `Resources.resw` file.

Like this:

[image]

The **Xaml code** should be like this:

```
    <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="SaveB" x:Uid="Save" Click="SaveB_Click" />
</Grid>
```

**Result:**

[image]

More information please refer to: [Localize strings in your UI and app package manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest)